# Deploying QGIS Python Standalone Application with minimum installation size

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to create a Standalone QGIS Application using python. I was able to create the nice looking shapeviewer application [by following the steps here](http://geospatialdesktop.com/2009/02/creating_a_standalone_gis_application_1/).

[image]

Now I would like to deploy this in another system.

Considering this is a small application, how can I keep the installation to a smaller size in the target machine?

Answer (score 5):

You will need the QGIS libraries, along with Qt and PyQt. You didn't mention what OS you are deploying for, but take a look at bb-freeze (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/) and py2app (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) for a way to bundle up the needed dependencies.