# Developing standalone gis applications using pyqgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, standalone

I am trying to develop a standalone application using pyqgis but I have no clue on where to start and where to write the code to make it happen so if anyone can provide me a tutorial to getting started, it'll be a  huge benefit for me. Thanks.

Comment: See this Q&A http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54198/how-to-deploy-a-qgis-python-standalone-application-with-minimum-installation-siz

Answer (score 2):

The best resource for this is the official documentation in the [pyqgis cookbook](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications)

Also a very useful resource is the [API documentation](https://www.qgis.org/api/) although aimed at C++ code and therefore not always applicable just like that it is very good for finding hints.

You can also search for [existing python plugins](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) and have a look at how they solved similar problems.

Comment: main problem im having is i cant find any step by step tutorial for beginers so that i can follow that at the initial stage and then i can use these resources to continue my project

Answer (score 1):

This guide is still generally applicable, even though it is written for the 1.x API:
http://geospatialdesktop.com/2009/02/creating_a_standalone_gis_application_1/

The upcoming *PyQGIS Programmers Guide* has an entire chapter on creating a standalone application with QGIS 2.x: http://locatepress.com/ppg